# How to create new user for SQL Server 2017 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I tried this:-

```
-- Creates the login dev with password 'Iamtesting123'.  
CREATE LOGIN dev1
    WITH PASSWORD = 'Iamtesting123';  
GO 

-- Creates a database user for the login created above.  
CREATE USER dev1 FOR LOGIN dev1;  
GO
```

Those commands completed successfully.

But then I tried to login by using those credential in Management Studio, I get this error:

[image]

How can I do make a new user so that he can access using Management Studio? Also, he should have enough privilege to make new database and table?

Comment: You should check SQL Server error log to find out the cause of 18456. It's the next row that you find after the error

Comment: Normally where is this log file stored?

Comment: C:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql10_50.mssqlserver\MSSQL\Log for 2008 R2

Comment: You can also use xp_readerrorlog to read it: just run exec xp_readerrorlog from your query window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this

Create User `dev1` with Password `MyPass`

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [dev1] WITH PASSWORD=N'MyPass' MUST_CHANGE, 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
```

Assign Roles to the User

```
USE [AdventureWorks]
GO
CREATE USER [dev1] FOR LOGIN [dev1]
GO
```

Comment: I didn't work for me. I get error as "TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to ESFIPC02\MSSQLSERVER17.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'dev3'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)